# what does it mean? <ul class="x-tree-root-ct x-tree-lines" id="ext-gen28">

Tags: html, css, class, html-lists

I see the following when inspect element using Chroms

```
<ul class="x-tree-root-ct x-tree-lines" id="ext-gen28">
```

What does it mean? In CSS, do I need to set styles for the two separately or together?

Sorry I am a CSS newbie.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate classes being applied: `x-tree-root-ct` and `x-tree-lines`.

`#ext-gen28` will select only that element.

`.x-tree-root-ct` will select any element with a `class` containing `x-tree-root-ct`.

`.x-tree-lines` will select any element with a `class` containing `x-tree-lines`.

`.x-tree-root-ct.x-tree-lines` will select any element where the `class` contains both `x-tree-root-ct` and `x-tree-lines`.

I have no idea which of those you actually want, because you haven't provided any context to your question.

Comment: can i do the following in css file?

Comment: .x-tree-root-ct, .x-tree-lines
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

Comment: That is valid CSS. It will zero the `margin` and `padding` on any element with a `class` containing either of `x-tree-root-ct` or `x-tree-lines`. See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorgrouping

Answer (score 2):

This means that there are multiple classes for this element. You can set styles on one class for the standard styles, then set additional styles using the other class. A common example could be:

```
<div class="black-box error">
```

In this example, black-box specifies the style for a standard black box. Then the error class only specifies styles for error, for example a red outline. Then you can use javascript to remove/add the error class quickly without having to target specific styles.